# How to create a custom a Moment.js locale per user in Meteor.js app?

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm working on a 1.5 Meteor.JS project and using moment.js official package. I need to give users the ability to choose the start of the week day.

How to create or alter locale **Start of week** option to meet each user need?

Comment: Why not just save that as a user preference and then use it in all date computations for that user?

Comment: that is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: How can we tell momentJS about each user preferences and put it to use in every computation for that user?

Answer (score 1):

`moment` lets you define a *locale* and alter the starting day of the week. For example to make Wednesday the first day of the week:

```
moment.locale('en',{
  week: {
    dow: 3
  }
});
```

[documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)

On the client this is easy since the client is only running as one user at a time. On the server you will need to switch dynamically in your methods.

Since you can have multiple locales and since there are only 7 possibilities you could create an array of locales and then just use the one that's pertinent to the current user's preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however there's still ambiguity like where this code should be located inside a meteor app?

Comment: both on the client and server - depending on where you are using moment. It needs to be run whenever the preference changes (either through initialization after login or because the user explicitly changed it). You can't really do it on startup since you might not have a user yet. A `Tracker.autorun()` could be handy.